# Problems at parallel fileupload with PHP/ProcessWire CMS and session.save_handler = redis/memcached

Tags: php, phpredis, processwire

I have an issue with PHP when I use session with save_handler redis or memcached.

I use the ProcessWire CMS and both session handler method working generally fine but I found one strange behaviour: I can't upload multiple images in parallel. The image which finishes at least are overriding all other uploaded images in the database.

Since yet, nobody used really ProcessWire with this session handlers and I guess it isn't a bug in ProcessWire itself. Maybe it is a bug in phpredis, memcached extension or PHP itself or I have some wrong configuration.

I used following in php.ini:

For Redis:

```
session.save_handler = redis
session.save_path = "tcp://127.0.0.1:6379"
```

For memcached:

```
session.save_handler = memcached
session.save_path = "127.0.0.1:11211"
```

Could it depend on something like session locking?
Deactivating/activating it doesn't help me.

The issue in the processwire github repo:
https://github.com/processwire/processwire-issues/issues/798

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I added following to my php.ini

```
redis.session.locking_enabled = 1
redis.session.lock_expire = 60
redis.session.lock_retries = -1
```